# Выводит SyntaxError: invalid syntax и не могу понять почему

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

Предистория: Я только начал изучать Python и учусь по книге от Зед А. Шоу "Легкий способ выучить Python". Так вот, там есть задание, которое нужно написать и выполнить в Терминале(я работаю на Маке)
Вот код:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import codecs, sys

outf = codecs.getwriter('cp866') (sys.stdout, errors = 'replace')
sys.stdout = outf

age = raw_input("Сколько тебе лет? ")
height = raw_input("Каков твой рост? ")
weight = raw_input("Сколько ты весишь? ")

print "Итак, тебе %r лет, в тебе %r см роста и %r кг веса."  % (age, height, weight)

# Выдает SyntaxError: invalid syntax и стрелка, указывающая на ошибку,
#где-то впереди, где пусто
```

Не ругайте строго, если Вам не понравилось, что учусь по этой книге.

Comment: Ваш код у меня запускается. Посмотрите внимательно, может где-то есть лишний знак,  попробуйте скопировать именно эти строки в другой файл, сохраните и запустите.

Comment: Скопируйте полный текст ошибки и вставьте в вопрос.

Comment: Рекомендую вам найти более современную книгу для изучения. То, что вы изучаете сейчас, станет бесполезно менее чем через год https://pythonclock.org/

Comment: Ну а проблема-то действительно очевидна: вы написали код для второго питона, а запускаете в третьем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, у вас третья версия питона.

Чтобы это проверить, последнюю строчку нужно изменить вот так:

```
print("Итак, тебе %r лет, в тебе %r см роста и %r кг веса."  % (age, height, weight))
```

Если заработает, то я прав, и вам нужно будет либо поставить себе вторую версию питона, либо заниматься по более современной книжке.

Comment: @Эникейщик если после принта стоят знак процента и скобки (а в коде автора они стоят), то прямой текст про print без скобок почему-то пропадает. Так что этот ответ вполне может оказаться верным

Comment: @andreymal  да, запустил третьем, так и есть.